# Grails/SpringSecurity: Getting locale in LogoutHandler

Tags: grails, spring-security

In a grails app, I'm successfully getting the language the user has selected(added to url, "...?lang=xx_XX") like this:

```
def locale = RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request)
```

Using springsecurity, and got a special logout handler set up that works fine

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.logout.handlerNames = ['securityContextLogoutHandler', 'myLogoutHandler']
```

I need to get the user selected locale in myLogoutHandler, but the following is not working (it only shows the browser default locale, not the one selected by the user)

```
class MyLogoutHandler implements LogoutHandler {
    void logout(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication) {
        def locale2 = RequestContextUtils.getLocale(httpServletRequest);
    }
}
```

I have also tried getting the session locale with:

```
RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getProperties()
```

but that gives the same result, anyone got an idea how to get the locale from the MyLogoutHandler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Workaround**

The session appears to be cleared by spring-security but you can still send in parameters.

so in the controller for the logout page I got:

```
def index = {
    def myParam = "bar"
    redirect(uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.logout.filterProcessesUrl + "?foo=" + myParam) // '/j_spring_security_logout'
}
```

And I just get the parameter in the LogoutHandler:

```
void logout(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication) {
    def myParam = httpServletRequest.parameterMap.get("foo")[0]
    ....
}
```

Comment: Works in 2.3.6 too, but need to use `grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.handlerNames` without the `s` in `plugins`

Answer (score 0):

I can get the locales by using the code below:

```
class CustomLogoutSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler {

    private static final ThreadLocal<Authentication> AUTH_HOLDER = new ThreadLocal<Authentication>()

    void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        AUTH_HOLDER.set authentication

        // reading locales...
        request.locales.each {locale ->println locale.toString()}

        try {
            super.handle(request, response, authentication)
        }
        finally {
            AUTH_HOLDER.remove()
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String determineTargetUrl(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Authentication auth = AUTH_HOLDER.get()

        String url = super.determineTargetUrl(request, response)

        // do something with the url based on session data..

        url
    }
}
```

Comment: Using request.locales.each() in my LogoutHandler only prints (en_US and en) which I suspect are just the locales sent in the request to my browser. It does not show the locale being set in the session by the user